# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%'

Tags: sql-server

I need to search the ffg table using the parameter ID(int) to the column Id(int), if ID is not supplied, I would like to return all data from that table. I have tried this query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE Id LIKE ISNULL (@id, '%')
```

But this query returns the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type
>   int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have to do inside `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE ID = ISNULL(@id, ID))
```

Here, if @id is null, the ID (the column value itself) is passed for comparison, which will always match and results in returning all data in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing an integer with "%"and you also using LIKE which both are wrong.
You need to use this

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (Id = @id) or (@id is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the [**`ISNULL`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) rule:

> *replacement_value* must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of *check_expresssion*.

In your condition:

```
ISNULL(@id, '%')
```

When `@id` is `NULL`, SQL Server tries to convert `'%'` to `INT` which causes the conversion error.

To return all rows if `@id` is `NULL`, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE 
    (Id = @id OR @id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to caste Id because it is integer so do like:

```
Where CAST(Id AS TEXT) LIKE '123%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to do this, but it returns this error "Explicit conversion from data type int to text is not allowed."